# SQL SERVER Select Distinct ID is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, for-xml-path, select-for-xml

I'm trying to get through to this sql Select statement below but I can't get it right.

```
Select DISTINCT vc.cid, vt.tid, vc.device,
    STUFF((select ', ' + c.tName from thumbTbl t2
                    join tags v ON t2.cid = v.cid
                    join config c on v.tid = c.tid
                    where vc.cid = t2.cid
                    group by c.tName 
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '') tName
from tags vt
    Inner join thumbTbl vc on vt.cid = vc.cid
    Left join config vtc on vt.tid = vtc.tid
order by vc.cid asc
```

The result as following:

```
cid tid device      tName
--- --- ---------   ---------
159 7   Mat Dwens    Escalation, Follow Up, More Benefits
159 11  Mat Dwens    Escalation, Follow Up, More Benefits
159 12  Mat Dwens    Escalation, Follow Up, More Benefits
160 7   Jeniffer P    Rectro
162 8   Marc Novice   More Benefits, Rectro
162 6   Marc Novice   More Benefits, Rectro
165 4   Jeniffer P    Follow up
```

Question: How to display only 1 row of each Selected Id?, *I tried to use `SELECT DISTINCT` But still gave me the same result and above.*

**The result That I want to see have to be like below:**

```
cid tid device      tName
------- ---------   ----------
159 12  Mat Dwens   Escalation, Follow Up, More Benefits
160 7   Jeniffer P  Rectro
162 8   Marc Novice More Benefits, Rectro
165 4   Jeniffer P  Follow up
```

**Does anyone have an idea?**

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff just add a sample data, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `DISTINCT` you're after, it's a `GROUP BY` and an aggregate fucntion on `tid`. The results ***are*** `DISTINCT` as you have a different value for `tid` on each row, however, what you want is the `MAX`. Due to a lack of sample data this is untested, however, I *think* this is correct:

```sql
SELECT vc.cid,
       MAX(vt.tid) AS tid,
       vc.device,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + c.tName
              FROM thumbTbl t2
                   JOIN tags v ON t2.cid = v.cid
                   JOIN config c ON v.tid = c.tid
              WHERE vc.cid = t2.cid
              GROUP BY c.tName
             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') AS tName --Changed to use .text() and also removed leading space
FROM tags vt
     INNER JOIN thumbTbl vc ON vt.cid = vc.cid
     LEFT JOIN config vtc ON vt.tid = vtc.tid
GROUP BY vc.cid,
         vc.device
ORDER BY vc.cid ASC;
```

Comment: did the trick, this pull it out, just that I did not want to use the `Max()` and `GroupBy` function. don't you have any other way besides `GroupBy` query?

Comment: Without sample data, I wouldn't like to hazard a guess, @PatsonLeaner . That, however, is different question now and should be posted as a new one.

Comment: I did, however provide the sample data up above on the question. can that be use full to you?

Comment: There's no sample data in the question, @PatsonLeaner , only results; the undesired results and the expected results. But that doesn't change my comment; if you want to ask about how to approach the problem differently that's a different question and you should ask a new one. Changing the question to that would invalidate both my and Gordon's answers, and would be reverted by the users or could easily cause the question to attract downvotes. Changing the question to invalided existing answers is very frowned upon by the community.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `SELECT DISTINCT` and the join to `config` in the outer query.  Then fix the inner query so it only brings in what you want from `config`:

```
select vc.cid, vt.tid, vc.device,
       stuff((select ', ' + c.tName
              from config c on v.tid = c.tid
              where v.tid = c.tid
              for xml path(''), TYPE
             ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(max)'
                    ), 1, 1, ''
            ) tNames
from tags vt join
     thumbTbl vc
     on vt.cid = vc.cid
group by vc.cid, vt.tid, vc.device
order by vc.cid asc
```

Comment: join tags v ON t2.cid = v.cid it's where I declare the v. Now in your code above v is not initiated. should I keep it? also `from` and `on` `Incorrect Syntax` under stuff